# Is this PDO quote() safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Is this PDO code safe? I'm not using `bindParam` or `bindValue`.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$username_q = $pdo->quote($username);

$sql_q = "INSERT INTO userdbs (username) VALUES ($username_q)";

$pdo->query(sql_q);
```

There might be some more problems in the code. Have started using PDO only today.

Comment: I've read that question. My syntax is different, and also, I am new to using PDO. So, I need to understand the problems with the code I've written.

Comment: Other problem with your code is that the string data requires wrapping in single quotes like this `$sql_q = "INSERT INTO userdbs (username) VALUES ('$username_q')";`

Comment: While your syntax is different, it does exactly the same thing. Your question *is* already answered. If you have remaining doubts, spell them out explicitly so we can address them specifically instead of repeating the same question that was already answered.